# p5js iframe doesn't work (Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user aborted a request)

Tags: html, iframe, p5.js

I put a p5js iframe tag in a .html file and opened it, but it doesn't show the p5js correctly.

The .html file just contains this line:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen src="https://editor.p5js.org/AlieNiT/full/DTFXjG_6a"></iframe>
```

[You can see the console logs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V8pB.png)

I expect that the iframe shows my p5js, but it just shows a 'loading...' message:

[The final result of opening .html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbtOo.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the p5.sound library is having trouble initializing inside a nested iframe. It doesn't you're using that library, so if you update your index.html to remove that reference it should start working.

Comment: Note I'm not sure why this would be the case. I tried tweaking the allowed features for the iframe to no avail. This might be worth opening a bug in p5.sound git repo (https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/)